# AngularJS e C# - model não traz valor se não for alterado

Tags: angularjs, viewmodel

Tenho um formulário onde alguns campos são numéricos (formato decimal com 2 casas).
Estou exibindo formatado e com máscara, tudo correto.

O que acontece é que, quando eu edito um dos valores, este valor editado é passado para o ViewModel do C# corretamente. Os demais valores (que existem, mas não foram editados) são passados para o ViewModel como 0 (zero).

Já tentei remover a máscara, mudar diretivas... mas nada adiantou.

O meu campo está assim:

```
<input ng-model="meuModelo.CubagemM3" type="text" maxlength="15" format="number" centsLimit="3">
```

Há ainda uma outra observação: quando o valor vem para a tela sem centavos (valor inteiro) e não é alterado, ao gravar, ele é passado normalmente para o ViewModel.

No ViewModel, a property está pública e com o tipo Decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o motivo: foi preciso formatar o valor retornado no javascript, antes de enviá-lo à action.

O sistema apresentava conflito (valor digitado: 123,45 - apresentado no Javascript como 123.45 e chegando zerado na action). Ao formatar para 123,45 no Javascript, funcionou.